# Box.net and WebDAV - Returned format seems wrong

Tags: webdav, box-api

I'm trying to grab a list of files/folders from Box.net using WebDAV (https://box.com/dav).

However, even though I'm constructing (what I think is) a valid WebDAV PROPFIND request.  The data is coming back from Box in HTML format.

I was expecting something like this:
http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#rfc.section.8.1.2

But, it comes back list this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Box WebDAV list</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.box.com/dav/A%20Test.pdf">A Test.pdf</a>
    </p>
    <p>
    ...
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a valid WebDAV response?

I'd much rather get back in the WebDAV format I've currently handled rather than custom parse it, but can do so if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try issuing your PROPFIND request to https://www.box.com/dav
I suspect by issuing it to https://box.com/dav you're getting a 301 redirect that your client is then turning into a GET request which will result in the HTML output you're seeing

Comment: Thanks. Thought it was something else, but after playing around with cURL I looked at the responses and you were quite correct.